# When using the ripgrep command in the Terminal how can I search for files which contain one pattern AND another pattern?

Tags: command-line, file-search, ripgrep

With [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) I want to list all files which contain `PATTERN_A` ***and*** `PATTERN_B`, possibly on different lines, but both patterns should be in the file.

I tried

```
rg -l -e PATTERN_A -e PATTERN_B /path/to/dir
```

but this finds all files containing `PATTERN_A` ***or*** `PATTERN_B` (or both, but not *only* files containing both patterns).

How can I find with `rg` all files contain *both* patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ripgrep can't really do this on its own. You could concoct something with the `-U/--multiline` flag, but the most robust way is to use shell pipelines and `xargs`.

First, the setup:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/rg-and
$ cd /tmp/rg-and/
$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" > a
$ printf "foo\nbar\nquux\n" > b
$ printf "baz\nbar\nquux\n" > c
$ printf "foo\nbar\nquux\nbaz\n" > d
```

And now the command:

```
$ rg -l -0 foo | xargs -0 rg baz -l
d
a
```

The `-l/--files-with-matches` flag tells ripgrep to only print the file path of files containing at least one match. The `-0` flag tells ripgrep to print the file paths terminated by NUL instead of by the newline character. Piping this into `xargs -0` causes each NUL terminated string from ripgrep to get turn into a CLI argument to its sub-command, `rg` in this case. The second `rg` command searches for the second term, `baz` and also asks ripgrep to print only the files matched. The result is a list of file paths containing both `foo` and `baz`, not necessarily on the same line.